# Please can anyone help me to find out the error in the xml file

Tags: android, xml, string

This is my strings.xml file on which i am getting an error and the error is "Apostrophe not preceded by \ ". Please can anyone help me for where i have been mistaken.

```
<string name="musamman_burj_overview">
  <p>Musamman Burj also called as the Saman Burj or the Shah-burj, is a beautiful octagonal tower erected close to the Shah Jahan's private hall Diwan-e-Khas in Lal Quila. \n\n As a matter of fact, the emperor Shah Jahan, who built the Taj, was imprisoned by his son Aurangzeb in the Agra Fort where he had a view on the building erected for his deceased wife.\n\n Shah Jahan is said to have passed away in the Musamman Burj, a tower with a spectacular marble balcony. From there one can probably have the best view on the Taj. Between the many pavilions, one can find small well maintained gardens. \n\n
    <font size="18" color="black"><b><u>Entry fee Structure:</u></b></font> \n\n Fee to this place is inclusive in the ticket to ‘Agra Fort’ 
  </p>
</string>
```

Comment: first googled ,before your posting the questions,possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420295/apostrophe-not-preceded-by-android-in-string-xml-file

Comment: Error has solution itself.., if you have read error properly....you could get solution.......

Comment: I don't think this even relates to XML. XML escaped single quote is &apos; and not \'

Comment: @Prag's- can you please explain it. I have tried but i dint get the solution.I am new to this.Please help.

Comment: Got your point.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put `'` without giving `\`.You have to provide escape to it wherever you are using `'`

Ex :

```
\‘Agra Fort\’
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your apostrophe:

Try changing

`Jahan's`

to

`Jahan\'s`.

Do the same wherever needed.